# Tab button is not working after clicking on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a form with a save button. On clicking save button, save function gets called and all the form data gets saved and moves to other page. Then when I go to the previous page then tab button stops working. The only way to make the tab button work is to refresh the page.

I have tried giving tabindex but still facing the same issue.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="customeruser" ng-show="custom_user">
<form name="userForm">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header active left">
                <i class="material-icons tclose">add</i>
                <i class="material-icons topen">remove</i>
                Personal Information
            </div>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="user.first_name">
                        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input class="passhints" name="password" ng-model="user.password" id="password"
                            type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
                        <label for="password" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Password*</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header left">
                <i class="material-icons tclose">add</i>
                <i class="material-icons topen">remove</i>
                Other information
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="user.last_name">
                <label for="first_name">Last Name</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="left" ng-show="custom_user">
        <button type="submit" id="savechanges" ng-click="saveUser()">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller.js

```
    $scope.saveUser = function () {
    Restangular.all("users/createuser/").post($scope.user).then(
        function (user_status) {
            $scope.user.id = user_status
            if (user_status > 0) {
                swal({
                    title: "Success!",
                    text: "User was successfully created!",
                    type: "success",
                    confirmButtonText: "OK"
                },
                    function (isConfirm) {
                        if (isConfirm) {
                            $state.go('manage');
                        }
                    });
            }
        },
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code for saveUser() and explain what you mean by "moves to other page" and "go to previous page"?  My guess is that your saveUser() function disables the form and you never leave the page but are dynamically changing the content on the existing page.

Comment: @StealthSpoder I have added the saveUser().

Comment: What has tab focus when you go back to /manage? It's gotta be somewhere, maybe in the location bar or one of the browser buttons? Can you add a $timeout function to focus() the element with tab index 0 when the controller initializes?

Comment: @kendavidson Element gets focused but the tab button still doesn't work. I tried with and without giving tab index.